# Shortcodes in CMB2 field in Wordpress not displaying

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode, formidable

I have a Wordpress site which uses the [CMB2](https://wordpress.org/plugins/cmb2/) and [Formidable Form Pro](https://formidablepro.com/) plugins and theme built with [timber](https://github.com/jarednova/timber).

The formidable form works properly in the page body but I can't get shortcodes to work in a custom meta-box WYSIWYG field. The same issue occurs with textarea_small fields.

Any idea how I can get shortcodes to work in custom meta box fields.

Comment: Links to plugins being used. Modified question for clarity. Hopefully the intent of the question is still clear. Hope the edit helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to wrap the retrieved post meta with do_shortcode().

Others have also said use apply_filters('the_content', $content);